# How to connect an iPad to a Macbook's proxy server / app?

Tags: ipad, network, safari, bluetooth, proxy

It used to be at work, we can set our iPad's Proxy to something like `12.34.5.67`, port `8888`, and then this iPad will be able to connect to our Macbook Pro machine (which is connected to the company network by VPN).

With the port `8888`, it actually can connect to an app that's called [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) that can fetch any webpage for us, or override any HTML, JavaScript, or CSS files using a local file on the hard drive for us to do debugging.

But recently, the network configuration has changed and we can't connect to the Macbook Pro any more.  We can still do the same old way if we are at home, using a local IP address like `192.168.1.80`.  So is there any way at all to make this work?  By using Bluetooth, for example, or by the connection cable, just somehow be able to connect to the Macbook to port `1888` or `3000`, and we can always use `rsh` to route it to our `8888` if needed.  The ultimate goal is to be able to use Safari on the iPad to use the Macbook Pro's port `8888` as a proxy.

Comment: so what has changed with network?

Comment: I think the IT team might have set up some firewall or disabled in the router for a local machine to connect to another local machine

Comment: Can you talk to them?

Comment: I'd imagine if they require the network to be more secure this way, we should still be able to use a way to let the iPad access to our Macbook's proxy server